# std::thread::join() hangs on somecase when using vs2017

Tags: multithreading

A similar problem:
https://web.archive.org/web/20150501080609/https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/747145

It seem has been solved in VS2017 when only compile this code. But when it compile with other code, thread.join() will hang.

Call stack:

```
rpcrt4.dll!NdrClientCall2() 
sdckern.dll!00000001803b5230()
sdckern.dll!00000001803b7a7e()
sdckern.dll!0000000180365b1e()
```

I'm not sure what "other code" in my project will affect it, and I can not offer the whole project here.
But when I fall opencv-4.2.0 to opencv-3.4.2, the problem disappear.

Comment: Now I use thread.detach() to avoid this problem.

Comment: Another point， it works normally in linux.